# Pandas CSV file with occasional extra columns in the middle

Tags: python, pandas

I'm processing lots (thousands) of ~100k line csv files that are produced by someone else. 9 times out of 10 the files have 8 columns and all is right with the world. The 10th time or so ~10 lines will have 2 extra columns inserted after column 6: (For simplicity lets assume the values in all the rows have the same value.)

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
A,B,C,D,E,F,Foo,Bar,G,H
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
A,B,C,D,E,F,Foo,Bar,G,H
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
```

I don't have control over the generation of the data files and need to clean them on my end, but I believe that rows with extra columns have corrupted data so I just want to reject them for now. I figured a simple way to handle this would be to initially load my data into a 10 column DataFrame:

```
In [100]: df = pd.read_csv(data_dir + data_file, names=ColumnNames)

In [101]: data_df
Out[101]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 99531 entries, 0 to 99530
Data columns:
time             99531  non-null values
var1             99531  non-null values
var2             99531  non-null values
var3             99531  non-null values
var4             99531  non-null values
var5             99531  non-null values
var6             98386  non-null values
var7             29829  non-null values
extra1           10  non-null values
extra2           10  non-null values
dtypes: float64(3), int64(5), object(2)
```

And then check for where extra1 or extra2 isnull, keep those rows, and then drop the extra rows.

```
data_df = data_df[pd.isnull(data_df['extra1']) & pd.isnull(data_df['extra2'])]
del data_df['extra1']
del data_df['extra2']
```

This seems a little round about / non-ideal. Does anyone have a better idea of how to clean this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to drop the bad lines, you might be able to use `error_bad_lines=False` (and `warn_bad_lines = False` if you want it to be quiet about it):

```
>>> !cat unclean.csv
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
A,B,C,D,E,F,Foo,Bar,G,H
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
A,B,C,D,E,F,Foo,Bar,G,H
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
>>> df = pd.read_csv("unclean.csv", error_bad_lines=False, header=None)
Skipping line 3: expected 8 fields, saw 10
Skipping line 5: expected 8 fields, saw 10

>>> df
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
1  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
2  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
3  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
4  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
```

Comment: Can you please look into this issue ? It's a similar one as above but the flags mentioned above are not working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51635417/runtimeerror-while-reading-tab-separated-text-file-into-pandas-dataframe