# Pandas: Append existing CSV file, extra columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm trying to create csv file, save it, read it later and then add (`concat`) data to the bottom - and do this process multiple times.  As an example, my setup is:

```
import pandas as pd

df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=('col1','col2'))
df3.to_csv('example.csv', sep=',')
print(df3)
```

which generates a blank csv file only containing column headers that looks like this (this is what i want my data to look like):

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1, col2]
Index: []
```

Then, I generate a new dataframe with row information (index), open the old (`df3`) csv file and `.concat()` to the file.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':list("abc"),'col2':list("def")})
df3 = pd.read_csv('example.csv', sep=',')
print(df3)
print(df1)
df3 = pd.concat([df3, df1], ignore_index=True)
print(df3)
df3.to_csv('example.csv', sep=',')
```

but when I read the `example.csv` file (`df3`) it actually generates a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Unnamed: 0, col1, col2]
Index: []
```

There is now an extra column.

My actual code constrains the `.read_csv`/`.to_csv` and it throws an error because what I'm trying to read/write in isn't what I sent it (I don't think).

I've tried adding `ignore_index=True` to the method but that doesn't do it.  I've also tried reading back exactly what I put in, but it still generates the `Unnamed` column.

There is some information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062470/pandas-csv-file-with-occasional-extra-columns-in-the-middle) on bad data within the column - not quite on point.

There is obviously a simple answer to this, I just can't figure it out.

Comment: `df3.to_csv('example.csv', sep=',', index=False)`

Comment: Perhaps the better approach is `.append()`, but based on the docs that doens't seem like the right approach.

Comment: @roganjosh - that worked...  I now see that the `index=` has several variables.  I now understand that the extra column is the index column from the original dataframe.  So I could also `.read_csv()` with `index=0` and that puts the `Unnamed:` column to the df's index.  Right?

Comment: From what I can tell, you will no-longer have `Unnamed:` as a column. The `to_csv` method will write a numerical index for each row unless you specify it as `False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read the csv file into `df3`, you can use

```
df3 = pd.read_csv('example.csv', sep=',', index_col=0)
```

Then you won't have the unnamed column.

Comment: Based on my question this is in fact the solution.  You can also use @roganjosh comment and save the csv without the index.  Both worked.  Thanks.